# FORTRAN77 How to throw error for the following: division symbol, timeout, very big floating value:

Tags: error-handling, fortran

1  for certain symbols like (/), (,) and (;) while taking input. 
2. Timeout error while taking input 
3. very big floating value as input
4. and for improper inputs like - 4/3

Comment: I really have no clue what it is you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to check user input for correct values and interpret lists and fractions. I'm assuming you mean from console, a la

```
read(*,*) character-variable
```

The other option is to use formatted input, for example

```
read(*,'(i4)') integer-variable
```

which would read an integer with four digits.

This method would possibly already remove some of your problems, because the user input has to match the specified format or the program reports a runtime error. It is possible to specify the number of input values as well (separated by whitespace, ',' or ';'). Hence if you know beforehand how many values you are getting, the user can enter lists. If you make the requirements clearer, it will be easier to help. Fortran is a bit finicky for I/O.

If you really need the input to be of a general not-defined-at-compile-time type, you'll have to parse the string. This is also true if you want the user to be able to enter fractions like '4/3'.

I'm not aware of a method to restrict the time which a user has to enter values. It may be possible, but I've never seen it.

For too big or improper values you just can, for example, wrap the read statement in an endless do loop and exit if the number(s) is/are correct

```
do
  read(*,'(i6)') x
  if ( (x.lt.1e5).and.(x.ge.0) ) exit
end do
```

This would request an integer x from the user until the input is smaller than 100 000 and at least 0.

edit after discussion in comments:

The following code may be what you want:

```
implicit none
integer :: x
character(len=10) :: y
y=''
print*,'Enter one integer:'
do
  read(*,'(i10,a)') x,y
  if( (y.eq.'').and.(x.lt.1e5) ) exit
  print*,'Enter one valid integer, smaller than 100 000, only:'
end do
print*,x
end
```

It just reads until there is exactly one integer smaller than 100 000 in the input. If you want a better user experience you can catch 'very' invalid input (that the program complains about and stops) with the iostat parameter.
One thing though: on my two available compilers (GCC 4.4.7 and Intel fortran compiler 11.0) the forward slash '/' is not a valid integer input and the program stops. If that is different for your compiler the code above should still work, but I can't test that.

Comment: I want to throw an error if the user does not input anything during read statement. Also i want to throw an error when the user inputs symbols like / , ; where an integer is needed for input. also fortran interprets a very big float value as INFINITY, so I want to prompt the user that the input value is too big.

Comment: If you tell Fortran to read an integer (look for 'formated input' or the two examples above without two asteriks in the read statement) it will only accept integers as input. Everything else crashes with a message. To make sure that the input is smaller than an arbitrary threshold, look at the last code snippet in the answer. It had an error because I wrote 'i4' instead of 'i6' and thus the input was always cut off after the first 4 digits, never triggering the 'too big condition', but I fixed that now. If you want improved error handling, look up the 'iostat' parameter of the read-statement.

Comment: iostat does not crash for the following symbols: comma, front slash, and the period. Also if a user inputs something like '4/3' it just reads 4 and ignores the rest. I want to prevent this from happening and say '4/3 is illegal, enter an integer'

Comment: Now it becomes clearer what you want. I'll edit in code in the answer, because it's easier to read there.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to time-out the program after a specific time:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gfortran.pdf (find: alarm)